# Auto select based on option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select

I was googling around and saw a tutorial on YouTube that uses JavaScript to auto select options based on the select value.

The JavaScript code looks like this:

```
$("select[value]").each(function() {
$(this).val(this.getAttribute("value"));
});
```

And the code that is in the HTML is this (after PHP gets the data)

```
<select name="group" id="group" value="4">
    <option value="1">Administrator</option>
    <option value="2">Member</option>
    <option value="3">Developer</option>
    <option value="4">Moderator</option>
    <option value="5">Donator</option>
</select>
```

The value in the select is supposed to tell the JavaScript what is to be selected, but it's not working for me, help me please? (I'm new to JavaScript/PHP/MySQL)

Comment: Works in Chrome (17.0/win7). See http://jsfiddle.net/Jwjpu/

Comment: After looking at your jsfiddle, I noticed I wasn't telling it load the function on page load, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code uses the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/). Given you haven't tagged your question with jQuery, I suspect maybe you don't realise that it is needed and haven't included the jquery.js file?

Add this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

(To load it from Google's CDN.)

Comment: I have included the jQuery in (I use it for other things)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

then try like mine, may be can help you

```
$(function(){
   var val = $("select[name=group]").val();  
   $("select[name=group]").change(function(){
        val = $(this).val();
    });
}
```